# NodeJS: Keeping large JSON in memory

Tags: json, node.js

I have a nodejs app which uses a simple key/value json object to match a list of item IDs to a list of keywords. e.g.

```
{
  keyword1: [ ... ],
  keyword2: [ ... ]
}
```

The app isn't responsible in managing or altering the list. It comes cached in a json file which doesn't change. In the app all I need is to be able to get the list of IDs based on a specific keyword. That's all.

My initial thought was to load up the JSON in memory at server startup and keep it, and just use a service to access the needed data. The only problem is that I'm not sure how this would affect the server. The JSON file is pretty big, ~30mb with about 10.000 keys. Would the server have performance issues because of this? My hunch is that it shouldn't, since accessing the data in the object should be pretty fast, but I'm not sure how it would react to large amounts of traffic.

Any thoughts?

(the alternative would be to import the data in a database, of course)

Comment: You should 1) test 2) wonder why you worried for 30 MB

Comment: @DenysSéguret So you're saying I shouldn't be worried for node handling the 30mb json? Also, I agree about testing :)